# iphone dev - activity indicator scroll with the table

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, uiactivityindicatorview

In a view of my app I subclass tableViewController and has an activity indicator shown up when the table content is loading. I put it in the center of the screen but it scroll with the tableView (I guess the reason is I add it as a subview of the table view). Is there a way that I can keep the activity indicator in the center of the screen even the table is scrolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either subclass a `UIViewController` instead, and set a table property, adding a `UITableView` as a subclass to the `UIView`, making it behave exactly like a `UITableViewController`.

Or, more simply, you could just add the `UIActivityIndicator` as a subview to the main window.

Comment: +1. It is so much more flexible to subclass `UIViewController` and add a table view and other subviews to it, than to be confined to a table view controller.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I subclass UIViewController and it works fine now =)